# Error - Unable to enumerate all disks esxi6.7

Tags: esxi

I have moved a VM from esxi 4.1 to esxi6.7, and when I try to start it, I got this error Unable to enumerate all disks.. Could anyone please give some advice.

Thank you all!

Comment: When moving between versions like this, I believe you need to run the converter to be able to power on the given VM again. Just copying the files from an old datastore nd host to a new set will not help in this case.

Comment: What research and processes have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers I solved this by exporting the VM as a OVF template...and it works..